# Issue removing a node from a linked list

Tags: c

Since the code was cryptic I decided to reformulate it.

This code is trying to remove the second element from a linked list (the node with number 2 on "int data"). The first parameter of remove_node is the address of the first pointer of the list, so if I have to remove the first pointer of the list I am able to start the list from the next pointer.

The problem is inside the second while loop, inside the if clause, more specifically with the free(previous->next) function, it is changing the address pointed by address_of_ptr (aka *address_of_ptr) and I can't understand why this is happening. Could someone enlighten me?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
  struct node *next;
  int data;
} node;

void remove_node(node **address_of_ptr, int int_to_remove)
{
  node *previous;

  while (*address_of_ptr != NULL && (*address_of_ptr)->data == int_to_remove)
  {
    previous = *address_of_ptr;
    *address_of_ptr = (*address_of_ptr)->next;
    free(previous);
  }
  previous = *address_of_ptr;
  address_of_ptr = &((*address_of_ptr)->next);
  while (*address_of_ptr != NULL)
  {
    if ((*address_of_ptr)->data == int_to_remove)
    {
        address_of_ptr = &((*address_of_ptr)->next);
        free(previous->next);
        previous->next = *address_of_ptr;
        /*or
        previous->next = (*address_of_pointer)->next;
        free(*address_of_pointer); 
        address_of_pointer = &previous->next;
        */
    }
    else
    {
        previous = *address_of_ptr;
        address_of_ptr = &((*address_of_ptr)->next);
    }
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  node *head = malloc(sizeof(node));
  node *a = malloc(sizeof(node));
  node *b = malloc(sizeof(node));
  head->next = a;
  a->next = b;
  b->next = NULL;

  head->data = 1;
  a->data = 2;
  b->data = 1;

  remove_node(&head, 2);

  return 0;
}
```

I figured it out using pythontutor.com.

Here is an image of the execution about to replace *address_of_ptr* with the address of the next pointer in the list:

[about to replace *address_of_ptr*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqMAr.png)

In my mind what would happen is that *address_of_ptr* would move from *head* to *a*:

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2r9l.png)

But what actually happens is this:

[*address_of_ptr* move from head to the first node's *next* variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56UPn.png)

Which is also the address of the next node (such as *a*).

Inside the if clause:

[*address_of_ptr* is set to the second node's *next* variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjsIq.png)

What I was expecting was it being set to *b*:

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFtRv.png)

Since it becomes equivalent to *previous->next*, it causes program to free *address_of_ptr*.

Comment: Note that you can only accept one answer. However, since you now have more that 15 reputation points, you can also upvote all answers that you found useful. This is not limited to one answer.

Comment: I have reverted your most recent edit, because it invalidated most of my answer. Please don't change your question in such a way that it invalidates answers. If you want to apply the fixes to your code and show that new code, then please post that new code in your own answer, instead of overwriting the question.

Comment: Actually, maybe it was good that you removed the wrong comment in your code, because it was misleading people who were reading your question. Therefore, I put that change back in, even if it invalidated the part of my answer in which I pointed out that the comment was wrong. I have now removed that part of my answer. However, the other errors in your question's code should stay, otherwise most of my answer would get invalidated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if the first `while` loop stops due to `*address_of_ptr == NULL`, then the line

`address_of_ptr = &((*address_of_ptr)->next);`

will cause undefined behavior, due to deferencing a `NULL` pointer. However, this will not happen with the sample input provided by the function `main`, so it is not the cause of your problem.

---

Your problem is the following:

When first executing inside the `if` block of the second `while` loop (which will be in the first iteration of the second `while` loop with your sample input), `address_of_ptr` will point to the `next` member of the first node in the linked list, so the pointer will have the value of `&head->next`. This is because you have the line

`address_of_ptr = &((*address_of_ptr)->next);`

in several places in your program, and it will execute one of these lines exactly once by the time you enter the `if` block.

The first line of that `if` block is also the line

`address_of_ptr = &((*address_of_ptr)->next);`

so that after executing that line, `address_of_ptr` will point to the `next` member of the second node in the linked list, so the pointer will have the value of `&a->next`.

At that time, the value of `previous` will be `head`, because at the time

`previous = *address_of_ptr;`

was executed, `address_of_ptr` had the value of `&head`.

Therefore, when the next line

`free(previous->next);`

is executed, `previous->next` will have the value of `a`, which ends the lifetime of that node. As already stated, at this time `address_of_ptr` will have the value `&a->next`, which means that `address_of_ptr` is now a dangling pointer, because it is now pointing to a freed memory location. Therefore, it is not surprising that `*address_of_ptr` changes after the `free` statement, because freed memory can change at any time.

---

Note that the function `remove_node` can be implemented in a much simpler way:

```
void remove_node( node **pp_head, int int_to_remove )
{
    node **pp = pp_head, *p;

    //process one node per loop iteration
    while ( (p = *pp) != NULL )
    {
        //check if node should be removed
        if ( p->data == int_to_remove )
        {
            //unlink the node from the linked list
            *pp = p->next;

            //free the unlinked node
            free( p );
        }
        else
        {
            //go to next node in the list
            pp = &p->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first loop, `previous` might be assigned something that's freed, so might have a non-crashing (but not correct) value. It's not obvious, so it's good practice to declare variables in the smallest scope you can and not reuse them, so they don't have unrelated stray values. In this case might be good to split this into two functions (it could also be refactored to a single loop, but if you're just learning then take one step at a time).

Comment: Maybe my logic is not easy to follow, but in the first iteration of the second while loop the if clause will NEVER be valid because of the use of the first while loop.
So PREVIOUS will always be assigned *BEGIN_LIST value.

Comment: I am sorry, but your answer does not solve the previous revision of the question. As I stated before the if clause will never be valid on the first iteration of the second loop. Previous will always point to a valid object.
I just added the statements between the loops to avoid people to misinterpret the code like you did.

Comment: @isley: Yes, you are right. My answer was wrong. I have now written a completely new answer. I have also written a much simpler version of your function `remove_node`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thank you for your elaborated answer! I am sorry if I was rude before, was my mood at the time speaking. I already fixed the mistake you pointed out regarding the lines between the loops when *address_of_ptr == NULL, thanks for pointing that out. Now I will focus on the next part of the answer. Anyway, thank you so much for taking the time to answer me.

Comment: @isley: There was nothing rude about what you wrote. You were right about my previous answer being wrong, so it was correct of you that you pointed it out.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I just read the later part of your explanation, thanks for that too, helped me clarify even more the thoughts on my mind. Concerning the suggestion you made by the end of the post, I reached the same conclusion after reading "Linus on Understanding Pointers" which David C. Rankin mentioned, and also noticing that the previous pointer and address_of_ptr was always pointing inside the same node. Although I developed a solution (will post it after writing this answer) using just an extra pointer to hold the node to be deleted, is there a reason you declared node **pp?

Comment: @isley: You are right that I could have simply renamed the function argument `pp_head` to `pp` and removed the additional variable. However, in my opinion, the code is easier to read that way. It is clear that the function argument `pp_head` always points to the pointer to the head node, and that `pp` is used to traverse the linked list. Also, some people consider it bad practice to modify the function argument (even though the language allows it), so I decided to modify a copy instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to thank everyone who helped me sorting this issue, I truly appreciate your effort in making the explanation clear as possible. After a lot of thinking a solution that I believe is much simpler than my first code come up. @David C. Rankin mentioned ["Linus on Understanding Pointers"](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/), and I think "I might have grasped" what Linus was referring to:

```
void remove_node(node **address_of_ptr, int int_to_remove)
{
  node *to_remove;

  while (*address_of_ptr != NULL)
  {
    if ((*address_of_ptr)->data == int_to_remove)
    {
        to_remove = *address_of_ptr;
        *address_of_ptr = (*address_of_ptr)->next;
        free(to_remove);
    }
    else
    {
        address_of_ptr = &(*address_of_ptr)->next;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
begin_list = &previous->next;
```

You might be mis-thinking how pointers to pointers work. Since `begin_list` is a `t_list **`, you generally want to assign to `*begin_list`. Also, since `previous->next` is already an address, you don't want to assign the address to `*begin_list`, just the value, so this should work instead:

```
*begin_list = previous->next;
```

Same for the similar line below it.

Comment: It can actually work that way, See [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/)

Comment: Interesting, I learned something. But I don't think that was the intent here.

Comment: Or a correct implementation here. He is using both a pointer and the address of the pointer, but `begin_list` itself is local to the function, so you are correct that `begin_list = &previous->next;` will not update anything in the original list.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared an answer last night several minutes after you asked the question at first, and put a lot of thought into it, but didn't come back until just now.  I'd let my version go, but it's a more detailed look into the problem anyway, so I thought I'd include it for posterity.

---

The problem lay on line 36:

```
                        begin_list = &(*begin_list)->next;
```

In the first `while` loop in the function `ft_list_remove_if`, I can see that you wanted to change the beginning of the list to point to some list item potentially later in the list; so for example, if you wanted to remove all items in the list which contained the string `"a"`, this function should indeed change the value of `list1` in the `main` function; this way the new start of the list would actually be `list2`.

However, by the time the second `while` loop is entered, there's no need to change the pointer to the start of the list anymore; that was taken care of in the first `while` loop.  As such, `begin_list` should really not be used anymore; it is a pointer to a pointer to a list item, so it references the variable which points to a list item.  This is not desirable.  Let's step through the program line-by-line and I'll show you what I mean.

---

Upon entering the function `ft_list_remove_if`, we run past the first `while` loop since the first element of the list does not contain the data `"b"`:

```
    while (*begin_list != 0 && (*cmp)((*begin_list)->data, data_ref) == 0)
        {
                [...]
        }
```

We're still on the first list item when we enter the second `while` loop, and the first item does not match.  We therefore go to the `else` branch of the `if` statement on line 25:

```
                if ((*cmp)((*begin_list)->data, data_ref) == 0)
                {
                        [...]
                }
                else
                {
                        previous = *begin_list;
                        begin_list = &(*begin_list)->next;
                }
```

In the `else` branch, `previous` is set to the first item in the linked list.  Fair enough.  Then `begin_list` is set to *the address of the `next` member of the first list item*.  This means that **when the first list item's `next` member changes, so does the value of `*begin_list`**.  Let that point sink in.

Now we go on to the next iteration of the `while` loop.  This time `*begin_list` points to the second list item, which does indeed match the search criteria, so we enter the main `if` branch instead of the `else`:

```
                if ((*cmp)((*begin_list)->data, data_ref) == 0)
                {
                        previous->next = (*begin_list)->next;
                        free(*begin_list);
                        begin_list = &previous->next;
                }
```

OK.  So let's remember here:  `previous` is set to the first item in the linked list.  `*begin_list` is set to the second item in the linked list.  But what is `begin_list` set to?  In short, the address of `previous->next`.  Remember the following from the last cycle of the loop?

```
                        previous = *begin_list;
                        begin_list = &(*begin_list)->next;
```

So now when `previous->next` is changed on line 28 to the third item in the list, `*begin_list` is *also* changed to the third item in the list!  That means that line 29 frees the memory allocated to the *third* item in the list, while the second item no longer referenced by any pointers!  By sheer luck, the program might continue to *look* like it functions properly for the next few steps, but it doesn't; the third element has been freed, and the contents of the third element get scrambled up a little bit and the third element's `next` and `data` members are filled with invalid data, resulting in the segfault.

**However**, the procedure worked when you copied `*begin_list` to `to_remove` first, and then freed the data pointed to by `to_remove`:

```
                        to_remove = *begin_list;
                        previous->next = (*begin_list)->next;
                        free(to_remove);
                        begin_list = &previous->next;
```

This is because `to_remove` continues to point to the second element, even after `*begin_list` has been changed by the `previous->next = (*begin_list)->next;` statement; thus the second element is freed as it should be, and on line 31 `begin_list` is set to the address of the third element, just like it should be.

---

That doesn't mean that the latter is a good solution.  Really, I think `begin_list` shouldn't be used at all beyond the first `while` loop, since it doesn't have to be.  My suggestion is to use another pointer named `current` with which you can step through the list:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct s_list
{
        struct s_list *next;
        void *data;
} t_list;

void ft_list_remove_if(t_list **begin_list, void *data_ref, int (*cmp)())
{
        t_list *previous;
    t_list *current;

        if (begin_list == 0)
                return;
        while (*begin_list != 0 && (*cmp)((*begin_list)->data, data_ref) == 0)
        {
                previous = *begin_list;
                *begin_list = (*begin_list)->next;
                free(previous);
        }
    current = *begin_list;
        while (current != 0)
        {
                if ((*cmp)(current->data, data_ref) == 0)
                {
                        previous->next = current->next;
                        free(current);
                        current = previous->next;
                }
                else
                {
                        previous = current;
                        current = current->next;
                }
        }
}

int ft_strcmp(char *s1, char *s2)
{
        int i;

        i = 0;
        while (s1[i] == s2[i] && s1[i] != '\0')
                ++i;
        return (s1[i] - s2[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
        t_list *list1 = malloc(sizeof(*list1));
        t_list *list2 = malloc(sizeof(*list2));
        t_list *list3 = malloc(sizeof(*list3));

        list1->data = "a";
        list2->data = "b";
        list3->data = "a";
        list1->next = list2;
        list2->next = list3;
        list3->next = 0;
        ft_list_remove_if(&list1, "b", &ft_strcmp);
        return (0);
}
```

Comment: Since your answer does not refer to the current question, but to [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67644959/1) of the question, you may want to post a link to that revision at the start of your question.

Comment: I wish every teacher on the world could be like this. Your explanation was extremely didactic, if I have to come back to refresh my memory on this matter I will sure use your answer. Even tho I found the solution myself before your post it helped greatly to see from someone else eyes how to approach the issue, and I loved your way of doing it. I would like just to point out something, when you say "and on line 31 begin_list is set to the address of the third element, just like it should be." The statement on line 31 is not changing begin_list.